# Find and replace within ID range

Tags: mysql

I have a large database over 1.5m rows. Currently I need to do a find and replace of something but I am getting errors which I assume is due to the large amount of data. I am using a find and replace command like this...

```
UPDATE  `email_queue` set `content_plain` = replace(`content_plain`, 'Replace this', 'with that');
```

A typical error is:

> 1206 - The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size

I am thinking then that it is due to the large amount of rows?? So what I am thinking is that it would be better to replace a smaller amount at a time. e.g: from id 1 to 50,000 and then from 50,001 to 100,000 etc etc

What would the sql command be to do that?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is just a web-based software to manage MySQL server databases.

Comment: You're replacing data without filter criteria. Is that what you want?

Comment: I would at least add a `WHERE` clause like `WHERE content_plain LIKE '%Replace this%'`

Comment: I read somewhere that I need to use the limit clause to do an update in batches... does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Run your command with the extension WHERE id > 1000 or WHERE id > 5000 and id < 1000

Comment: #1206 - The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size

Answer (score 0):

You should make your query more specific to begin with. But what you're asking, use `BETWEEN`"

```
... WHERE id BETWEEN 0 AND 50000
```

50,000 records is still a lot, might want to break it up further.

[Have a look at the manual.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Comment: So i tried
        UPDATE  `email_queue` set `content_plain` = replace(`content_plain`, 'Replace this', 'With this') WHERE id BETWEEN 692690 AND 693690;

But it did not seem to work...

Comment: what error did you get? If you didn't get one, either your `WHERE` clause didn't return any rows (ids are out of range) or none of your rows contain `Replace this` - which I don't imagine is the case.

Comment: I used some text instead of 'Replace this' of course.
Could you write out the complete command to insert? Many thanks

Comment: I tried this...
UPDATE  `email_queue` set `content_plain` = replace(`content_plain`, 'Replace this', 'with this'); WHERE id BETWEEN 692690 AND 693690

I got error:
#1206 - The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size

Comment: How do i get around seeing this?... "#1206 - The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size"